# enable gateway url for login django

Tags: django

I'm trying to figure out how can I open make a separate url and enable it as a gateway for login.

The idea is that I'll send a generated url something like `https://mywebpage/?token=12412414`, you will click on it and you will login into the web app.

The current setup allows me to create user over api, and I can obtain a token a for him using [jwt rest framework](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) which ideally I would send to you.

Can someone help me understand how to do this, this is my first time handling this kind a request, thanks.

Comment: do u mean - a click on link will auto-login user on your site?

Comment: yes, that i what I mean, I found out some examples on SO, but if you have an idea it would be nice to hear it